# Matrix is invertible, but jacobi iteration does not converge

Tags: math, parallel-processing, mathematical-optimization

I want to solve the linear equation Ax = b.

A is a square matrix and can be inverted. However, it does not converge when using jacobi to iteratively solve it. why? How to solve?

Comment: Is matrix A diagonally dominant?

Comment: Can you give the exact matrix your are trying to invert, and the actual code you use to invert it.